# Using sed to prepend zero to four-digit numbers

Tags: sed

I have a list of numbers, for example

1394

49020

344

34

4904290

2350

5

I am trying to prepend '0' to the four-digit numbers using sed, so the example above should give '01394' and '02350' and leave everything else as is.

The command I am using is `sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}/0&/'` but this includes numbers four digits and greater. I tried including end of line to indicate that I only want four digit numbers like so: `sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}$/0&/'` but this added a '0' to the second place of the five-digit numbers, so in the example above, '49020' would become '409020'.

Would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to prepend to *only* four-digit numbers, so you need to match beginning and ending, like this:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{4\}$/0&/'
```

I sometimes use something like this:

```
sed -r \
    -e 's/^[0-9]{1}$/0&/' \
    -e 's/^[0-9]{2}$/0&/' \
    -e 's/^[0-9]{3}$/0&/' \
    -e 's/^[0-9]{4}$/0&/' \
    -e 's/^[0-9]{5}$/0&/' \
    -e 's/^[0-9]{6}$/0&/'
```

which should leave all numbers as seven digits. There are of course easier ways with other tools than `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I find sed to be cranky.  That sed lol here's how you do it.  Instead of

```
 sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}/0&/'
```

Add in an end of string terminator:

```
 sed 's/^[0-9]\{4\}\>/0&/'
```

Note the /> after the second bracket.  = End of word.  It's stupid, don't know why specifying a len doesn't work. Maybe some experts can let us know why that is.

BTW tried with and without the string start caret - it works either way s/[0-9 or s/^[0-9]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{4\}$/0&/'
```

I was able to modify it with the -i command and space /filename. Like below.

```
sed -i 's/^[0-9]\{4\}$/0&/' /tmp/filename
```

It would prepend the 4 digit numbers in the file with a 0.

I then changed it to do other funky changes that I required.

Thanks a mill for this one!!!!!